# Redirect with htaccess should not access some pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 3 pages:

- **index.html**
- **about.html**
- **contact.html**

I need to create an htaccess that redirects to home (**index.html**) if the visitor **NOT go** to one of those 3 pages.

Example:

If I go to page: **asdf.html** then I get redirected to **index.html**

But if income **contact.html** shows me that page.

¿How I can do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|about|contact)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js)$).*$ /index.html [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: It works, but now do not load images, or JS files (jQuery) or CSS. How I can do so only file URLs are. Html? Thank you.

Comment: Excellent! ... and the last thing you need ... How do I can not go to any folder? Because when I go into some folders are redirected fine, but others do not. For example if I enter mysite.com/old/pag1.html shows me that page and does not redirect. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's wrong, I need the opposite: What NOT to enter any directory by the browser (but that can upload files from directories like css or images internally in the html). With the code that you modified, I can get into any directory.